# loader in require not executed

Tags: webpack, exports-loader

I use the lib [js-aruco](https://github.com/jcmellado/js-aruco) which is browser only. Thats why I try to shim that lib. I do it this way:

```
module.exports = require('exports-loader?CV!../js-aruco/src/cv.js')
```

In the bundle I can see the libraray included - but the `module.exports = CV` is missing.
However - a similar case is working:

```
module.exports = require('imports-loader?CV=./cv.js!exports-loader?AR!../js-aruco/src/aruco.js')
```

Here I can see the export. Ofc this code fails because it requires CV do be loaded correctly which is not the case.

The modules I require directly from my entry point are loaded correctly with the export loader. However, when using the export-loader with cv.js which is used by ar.js which is then incuded in my entry it just gets ignored.

The loader is not executed.

So my question: **Why is the exports-loader not executed?**

PS: My webpack config is the simplest one can imagine. Only entry and output